# For loop with append list

Tags: python, pandas, list, append, concatenation

"year" data not append s list.
for loop with files station number based later based items append "s" list. ?

```
s = []
    while t < t+1:
        for p in range(0,t):
            k = df_st3[p] == find_station+"-"+year
            if k == True:
                #print("Found :",year)
                return s.append(year)
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: I can derive absolutely no meaning from this.

Comment: Emirhan, It might be easier if you show more of your code. for example what does the dataframe `df_st3` look like. maybe print `df_st3[p]`? Either way, I think there is a more efficient way of doing it in a purely pandas way

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell for sure what is happening. My guess is that `df_st3[p]` is a series, `k` will never give true since a series cannot be equal to a string.

Please provide more details for more precise answer